# exchange powershell : finding the active directory office property

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server-2007

I wrote this small script to pull the office property from get-user by piping the exchange mailbox object.

```
$server = "tms08"
$arrUser = get-mailbox -Server $server |Get-MailboxStatistics |select identity
foreach ( $id in $arrUuser)
{
    $office = get-user -Identity $id.Identity |select office
    $out += $id.Identity 
}
$out
```

I don't get any output or red errors.  just the warning:

> WARNING:There is no data to return for
>   the specifed mailbox
>   'Globe/MobileElect Usertemplate',
>   because it has not been logged on to.
>   WARNING:By default only the first 1000
>   items are returned. To change the
>   number of items returned, specify the
>   parameter "-ResultSize". To return all
>   items specify "-ResultSize Unilimited"
>   (Note: REturning all items maytake a
>   long time and consume a large amount
>   of memory depending on the actual
>   number of items). It is not
>   recommended to store the results in a
>   variable; instead pipe the results to
>   another task or script to perform
>   batch changes.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

My goal is to develop a script which executes once a day via scheduled task which compiles all mailbox names, mailbox sizes, totalitems, totaldeleted items, along with their office and description fields (from active directory).

I'm guessing the get-qaduser is part of the quest powershell addon.  I'll install it locally and give it a try..

the identiy property seems to give a number similar to the guid which looks like 
1234as01-4f54-1234-b1df-f1df1df12d2d

I tried running

```
get-user -identity 1234as01-4f54-1234-b1df-f1df1df12d2d
```

and it found a name (joey blasio) and recipient type (usermailbox)

then i ran

```
get-user -Identity 1234as01-4f54-1234-b1df-f1df1df12d2d | select displayname, distinguistedname
```

> Displayname (Joey Blasio ) and DistinguishedName (CN=Joey
>   Blasio,OU=EWE,DC=BLA-1,DC=net)

Comment: would a better way to find the office property in Active directory is through binding the GUID property? I noticed the get-mailboxstatistics has a mailboxguid and the get-user has a guid property.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you're accessing a mailbox that's never been accessed normally. Can you try this with a mailbox that you know the owner has opened and worked with? Or is that already the case?

Also, as I don't have access to my Exchange machine at the moment, can you give me an idea of what the Identity property contains? I'm absolutely certain using a cmdlet like `Get-QADUser` vs. `Get-User` in Exchange, will ultimately bring you more satisfaction. We just need to mesh up the right property from `Get-MailboxStatistics` to something `Get-QADUser` can consume, so that it can get you the right user.

It might also be a bit helpful to understand what your end goal is - possibly there's an entirely different approach that will get you to where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

It is done by `DisplayName`

```
$exchangeservers = Get-MailboxServer
$AllUsers = @()
$AllUsersEmail = @()

foreach ($server in $exchangeservers)
{
    $AllUsers += Get-Mailbox -Server $server |Get-MailboxStatistics |select servername,displayname,itemcount,totalitemsize
}

foreach ($user in $AllUsers)
{
    $obj = new-object psObject
    $mailinfo = get-mailbox -identity $user.displayname |select PrimarySMTPAddress,Office, DistinguishedName
    $tmp = [adsi]("LDAP://" +  $mailinfo.DistinguishedName)


    $obj |Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "Server Name" -Value $user.ServerName
    $obj |Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "Display Name" -Value $user.DisplayName
    $obj |Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "Item Count" -Value $user.ItemCount
    $obj |Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "Total Item Size" -Value $user.TotalItemSize
    $obj |Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "Email Address" -Value $mailinfo.PrimarySMTPAddress
    $obj |Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "Office" -Value $mailinfo.Office
    $obj |Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "Description" -Value $tmp.description

    $AllUsersEmail += $obj
}

$AllUsersEmail |Export-Csv c:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```